# Problem send touchEvent to backView for make Scroll in tableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch, send, back

My problem is that I have a ScrollView and back I have other view with TableView.
I intercept the touch in the ScrollView and send the touchBegan, touchMoved, touchEnded and touchCancel

[tableView touchesXXXXXX:motion withEvent:event]; (XXXX is Began, Moved, ...)

These work for detect touchs, and I can select the row in the back tableView, but my problem is that can't make scroll in back tableView. How I can send the touch event for make scroll on tableView? Because sending the touchMoved event to tableView don't make scroll.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> **Important**: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

From UISCrollView [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)